# How .netstandard package is executed in classic .net project?

Tags: .net, dll, .net-standard-2.0

**.Net-Standard** class library contains **NetStandard.Library** sdk (it's a nuget meta-package actually) which contains a set of common .net apis. After compilation it produces **dll** with **.MSIL**. After that I can add this **dll** to classic .net project and it will be executed as usual .net **MSIL** by **JIT**.

1. Is it correct?
2. Is **NetStandardLibrary** is a just kind of guarantee that code in this dll uses only api available in both .net-core and classic.net?